# Autocomplete do jQuery UI só funciona uma vez

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Estou trabalhando em uma funcionalidade de uma aplicação Rails onde usamos uma gem chamada [Best in Place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place), que proporciona a possibilidade de edição inline de atributos de um model. Mas surgiu a necessidade de usar autocomplete do jQuery UI quando o usuário for editar algumas informações.

Procurando no SO em inglês, encontrei [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864750/in-place-editor-with-autocomplete). Tentei fazer da forma que o primeiro cara disse, pensando em **não** adicionar mais uma dependência à aplicação. Meu código JavaScript está assim:

```
$('#edit_objeto').on('click', function(event) {
  var self = $(this);
  var containerElement = $("#best_in_place_processo_9_objeto");
  var textField = containerElement.find("form input[type=text]");

  // Aqui está a parte problemática...
  textField.autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: containerElement.data('autocomplete-uri'),
    minLength: 2
  });

  return false;
});
```

Quando eu testo no navegador, funciona, mas só da primeira vez. Da segunda vez em diante já não funciona mais e não entendo o porquê. Fiz debug e notei que o evento `click` é acionado normalmente, mas essa parte específica do autocomplete do jQuery UI deixa de funcionar depois da primeira execução.

Alguém sabe me dizer onde eu estou errando?

Comment: Você já verificou se as variáveis `containerElement ` e `textField` continuam com mesmo valor ? Já verificou se a função `containerElement.data('autocomplete-uri')` continua retornando os dados corretamente?

Answer (score 1):

A função autocomplete deve ser definida somente uma vez, de preferência no carregamento da página. No seu código ela está vinculada ao evento click, e é redefinida cada vez que o elemento #edit_objeto é clicado, o que gera o erro.

Se não for usar as variáveis containerElement e textField em outras partes, você substituir sua função por:

```
$(function(){
    $('#id_do_input').autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: containerElement.data('autocomplete-uri'),
    minLength: 2
  });
});
```